# Is it possible to add a new similarity metric to an existing index in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, similarity

Let's say there is an existing index with a customized BM25 similarity metric like this:

```py
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "similarity": {
                "BM25_v1": {
                    "type": "BM25",
                    "b": 1.0
                }
            },
            "number_of_replicas": 0,
            "number_of_shards": 3,
            "refresh_interval": "120s"
        }
    }
}
```

And this similarity metric is used for two fields:

```py
{
    'some_field': {
        'type': 'text',
        'norms': 'true',
        'similarity': 'BM25_v1'
    },
    'another_field': {
        'type': 'text',
        'norms': 'true',
        'similarity': 'BM25_v1'
    },
}
```

Now, I was wondering if it's possible to add another similarity metric (`BM25_v2`) to the same index and use this new metric for the `another_field`, like this:

```py
"index": {
    "similarity": {
        # The existing metric, not changed.
        "BM25_v1": {
            "type": "BM25",
            "b": 1.0
        },
        # The new similarity metric for this index.
        "BM25_v2": {  
            "type": "BM25",
            "b": 0.0
        }
    }
}

# ... and use the new metric for one of the fields:

{
    'some_field': {
        'type': 'text',
        'norms': 'true',
        'similarity': 'BM25_v1' # This field uses the same old metric.
    },
    'another_field': {
        'type': 'text',
        'norms': 'true',
        'similarity': 'BM25_v2' # The new metric is used for this field.
    },
}
```

I couldn't find any example for this scenario in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html), so I wasn't sure if this is possible at all.

**Update**: I have already seen this old still-open [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6727) which concerns with dynamic update of similarity metrics in Elasticsearch. But it is not completely clear from that discussion what is and isn't possible. Also there have been [some attempts](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/20339) for achieving some level of similarity update; but I think it's not documented (e.g. it is possible to change the parameters of an existing similarity metric, say `b` or `k1` in an **existing** `BM25`-based metric).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TLDR;

I believe you can't.

```json
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Mapper for [title] conflicts with existing mapper:\n\tCannot update parameter [similarity] from [my_similarity] to [my_similarity_v2]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Mapper for [title] conflicts with existing mapper:\n\tCannot update parameter [similarity] from [my_similarity] to [my_similarity_v2]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

If you want to, I believe you will have to create a new field and re-index the data.

## To reproduce

```json
PUT /70973345
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "similarity": {
        "my_similarity": {
          "type": "BM25",
          "b": 1.0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /70973345/_mapping
{
  "properties" : {
    "title" : { "type" : "text", "similarity" : "my_similarity" }
  }
}
```

We insert some dummy data, and retrieve it.

```json
POST /70973345/_doc
{
  "title": "I love rock'n roll"
}

POST /70973345/_doc
{
  "title": "I love pasta al'arabita"
}

POST /70973345/_doc
{
  "title": "pasta rock's"
}

GET /70973345/_search?explain=true
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "pasta"
    }
  }
}
```

If we try to update it the settings [without closing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html#default-base), we get an error.

```json
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Can't update non dynamic settings ...."
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Can't update non dynamic settings ...."
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

```json
POST /70973345/_close?wait_for_active_shards=0
```

```json
PUT /70973345/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "similarity": {
      "my_similarity": {
        "type": "BM25",
        "b": 1.0
      },
      "my_similarity_v2": {
        "type": "BM25",
        "b": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The update works fine, **BUT** :

```json
PUT /70973345/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "text",
      "similarity": "my_similarity_v2"
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Mapper for [title] conflicts with existing mapper:\n\tCannot update parameter [similarity] from [my_similarity] to [my_similarity_v2]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Mapper for [title] conflicts with existing mapper:\n\tCannot update parameter [similarity] from [my_similarity] to [my_similarity_v2]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

It will not work, regardless of the `open`/`close` status of the index.

Which makes me believe this is not possible. you might need to `re-index` into a new indice the existing data.

Comment: All right, thanks a lot for checking this. But creating a new **field** on the same index and using the new metric for that field would be OK, right?

Comment: Yes, I have just tested. It works

Comment: I see, thanks. Before posting this question, I already saw this old still-open [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6727) which concerns with dynamic update of similarity metrics in Elasticsearch. But it is not completely clear from that discussion what is and isn't possible. Also there have been [some attempts](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/20339) for achieving some level of similarity update; but I think it's not documented (e.g. it is possible to change the parameters of an existing similarity metric).